# Problems with set up with the Test automation framework Selendroid

Tags: java, android, testing, automation, selendroid

I have problems with setting up the Selendroid server.
When i run the command `java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.11.0-with-dependencies.jar -app selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk`
I get the following errors:

```html
C:\Users\mawal2\Downloads>java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.11.0-with-dependenci
es.jar -app selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk
################# Selendroid #################
################# Configuration in use #################
io.selendroid.SelendroidConfiguration@19469ea2[
  port=4444
  timeoutEmulatorStart=300000
  supportedApps=[selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk]
  verbose=false
  emulatorPort=5560
  deviceScreenshot=false
  selendroidServerPort=8080
  keystore=<null>
  emulatorOptions=<null>
  registrationUrl=<null>
  proxy=<null>
  serverHost=<null>
  keepAdbAlive=false
  noWebViewApp=false
  noClearData=false
  sessionTimeoutSeconds=1800
  forceReinstall=false
  logLevel=ERROR
]
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
INFO: Starting selendroid-server port 4444
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x8
6_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\mawal2\Downl
oads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x8
6_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\mawal2\Downl
oads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x8
6_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\mawal2\Downl
oads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk META-INF/CERT.SF
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x8
6_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\mawal2\Downl
oads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.SF
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x8
6_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\mawal2\Downl
oads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.RSA
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x8
6_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\mawal2\Downl
oads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk META-INF/NDKEYSTO.SF
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x8
6_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\mawal2\Downl
oads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk META-INF/NDKEYSTO.RSA
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: executing command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\bin\jarsigner.exe
 -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:\Users\mawal2\Downloads\resigne
d-selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\mawal2\.a
ndroid\debug.keystore C:\Users\mawal2\Downloads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk a
ndroiddebugkey
Oct 16, 2014 7:57:24 AM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher launchServer
SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: An error occurred while resigning
the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk'.
io.selendroid.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: An error occurred while res
igning the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk'.
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:114)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(Selendro
idStandaloneDriver.java:82)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidS
erver(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:61)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStan
daloneServer.java:50)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java
:49)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:105)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured whil
e executing shell command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\bin\jarsigner.e
xe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:\Users\mawal2\Downloads\resig
ned-selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\mawal2\
.android\debug.keystore C:\Users\mawal2\Downloads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk
 androiddebugkey
        at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServer(Selendro
idServerBuilder.java:274)
        at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidSer
verBuilder.java:134)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:112)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException:
        ... 9 more
Exception in thread "main" io.selendroid.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException:
An error occurred while resigning the app 'selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk'.
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:114)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(Selendro
idStandaloneDriver.java:82)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidS
erver(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:61)
        at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStan
daloneServer.java:50)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java
:49)
        at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:105)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured whil
e executing shell command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\bin\jarsigner.e
xe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar C:\Users\mawal2\Downloads\resig
ned-selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\mawal2\
.android\debug.keystore C:\Users\mawal2\Downloads\selendroid-test-app-0.11.0.apk
 androiddebugkey
        at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServer(Selendro
idServerBuilder.java:274)
        at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidSer
verBuilder.java:134)
        at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplication
sUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:112)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException:
        ... 9 more

C:\Users\mawal2\Downloads>
```

I think the problem has something to to with either the java  or android environment variable.
I have read a lot of guides and forum postes and tried different ways, but i always end up with the same result. The env-variables are currently set-up in the following way:
Under "User variables for ":

- ANDROID_HOME: C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
- JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin

Under "System varibles":

- Path: %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\;C:\Users\mawal2\Documents\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\;

My OS is Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Am very grateful for all help i can get!

Best regards Magnus

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem when a `An error occured whil
e executing shell command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\bin\jarsigner.e
xe`

There are bin\bin after each other wich is not correct. Solved it by changing the Java home variable to:
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\

I also notice that for me variable changes are only done after restarting the computer, this may be the reason why didn't manage to solve it before.